# Sum by grouping using related tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have the tables

`costs`:

| id | type | year | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2020 | 400 |
| 2 | A | 2020 | 200 |
| 3 | A | 2021 | 100 |
| 4 | B | 2021 | 100 |
| 5 | B | 2021 | 200 |

`discounts`:

| id | id_cost | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 3 | 1 | 70 |
| 4 | 2 | 30 |
| 5 | 2 | 50 |

I need `amountSum` and `discountSum` to be the sums grouped by `year`

| type | year | amountSum | discountSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 600 | 190 |
| A | 2021 | 100 | 0 |
| B | 2021 | 300 | 10 |

What I tried:

```
SELECT
    costs.type,
    costs.year,
    COALESCE (SUM(costs.amount),0) AS amountSum,
    COALESCE (SUM(discounts.amount),0) AS discountSum
FROM
    costs
LEFT JOIN discounts ON costs.id = discounts.id_cost
GROUP BY
    costs.type,
    costs.year
ORDER BY
    costs.type ASC;
```

But it does not return `amountSum` correctly if there is more than one `discount` for the same `year`, for example: `A - 2020: 1200`.

| type | year | amountSum | discountSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 1200 | 190 |
| A | 2021 | 100 | 0 |
| B | 2021 | 300 | 10 |

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**: solution

```
SELECT type, year, SUM(amount) AS amountSum, COALESCE(SUM(d.discountSum),0) AS discountSum
FROM costs
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_cost, COALESCE (SUM(amount),0) AS discountSum FROM discounts GROUP BY id_cost ) D ON costs.id = D.id_cost
GROUP BY type, year;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What rule determines which discount amount to use? The one with the higher discount ID or the higher discount amount? By your sample data, probably just the `Max(Amount)` for each id_cost. Build aggregate query to pull Max(Amount) for each id_cost and join that query to Costs table.

Comment: @radocaw I have posted the solution in the answer. Thanks for the advice, if you can enable my account, I want to continue contributing to the community. Thanks!